# How does the Steam Marketplace change values without a URL change - Webscraping (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been recently working on web-scraping in **python** (using **selenium**) some steam data from their marketplace to track the prices of weapon skins.

I've come into an issue in which when a web-page is loaded (**without logging into steam**) it will display each sale in its individual currency whereas **I want all results in dollars**. If there are more than 10 results, then there will be multiple pages available and once you click on the second page all results appear in dollars and then when you click back on the first page all those results are now also in dollars. Here is an **example**:

Go to a item with 10+ results e.g: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AK-47%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29

Here's what it'll look like initially:
[image]

Then when you click on the second page at the bottom of the page and then click back on the first place this occurs.
[image]

So the issue with this occurs when I have rarer items which cannot go onto a second page. The code that I've created is setup so that it'll select the second page and then the first afterwards. Here is the code:

```
path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get(https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AK-47%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29)

try:
    pageloaded = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='market_paging_pagelink']"))
        )
    pageloaded.click()
finally:
    time.sleep(1)



try:
    pageloaded = WebDriverWait(driver, 12).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='market_paging_pagelink']"))
        )
    pageloaded.click()
    print("page successfully loaded...")
finally:
    time.sleep(1)
```

With the following imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

What I'd like to know is how does steam change it's currency without changing the URL and how can I force this event to occur without changing onto a page with less than 10 results or if I can get the data in some other way.

If anyone has any ideas as to how you can do this it would be much appreciated! :)